# PHP header redirect and HTML refresh

Tags: php, html, redirect, header, refresh

I am working with a php login page that redirects people to user specific pages. When the user gets to these pages it still shows the php login page in the url.

Can you help me find a way for the html (or php) code on the new page to reload the page one time so it becomes that page AFTER IT REDIRECTS. (I am having functionality problems with these pages because of this problem)?

Comment: `header('Location: newpage.php');`.

Comment: And what's your current code that ain't working?

Comment: I am using headers, the page needs to refresh after the redirect

Comment: Headers can not redirect after any output has been sent. Make sure headers are not send before you need to redirect

Comment: Then include a cache-busting query string, to prevent the destination page from being pulled from cache, e.g. even `header('Location: newpage.php?cachebuster=' . time());`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use PHP to refresh the page. Once the page is loaded into the browser, PHP is out of control and cannot modify the page contents.

To reload/refresh the document, you can use HTML or JavaScript.

To refresh the document every 30 seconds using HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Using JavaScript:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first one will be refresh automatically after 30 seconds. But for the second one, the page will only refresh when the button is clicked.